# What's the difference between Sample and tex2D

Tags: shader, texture, directx11, unity

I am mainly using Unity but I think that it's not related to this engine, and I am wondering what's the difference between using [`tex2D`](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/Cg/tex2D.html) and [`Sample`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509695(v=vs.85).aspx) for sampling a texture.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They represent the same operation, but `Sample` is what it's called in D3D10 and newer versions of HLSL, while `tex2D` is what it's called in D3D9 HLSL, and NVIDIA's (defunct) Cg language. By the way, the operation is also called [`texture`](http://docs.gl/sl4/texture) in GLSL.

Comment: Thanks Nathan ! Is this just a new call or does it also include some performance boost. I mean what does this call imply compared to the D3D9 version ?

Comment: @MaT It implies you're using D3D10+. ;) It's literally the same operation in hardware; they just redesigned the API and called it a different name.